# Return a formula with evaluated members

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a function that returns the formula of its input cell, replacing all references to other cells with the cells' values. My current implementation works fine unless the input cell contains absolute references, which is what I'd like to improve upon.

Currently, I extract the Range.FormulaR1C1 property of the input cell and replace all addresses with values of their respective cells. It's fairly easy to recognize relative addresses, because they contain square brackets, i.e. []. The general format is R[*rN*]C[*cN*] with *rN* and *cN* denoting relative row or column numbers (integer values) - if either of these equals zero, it gets omitted along with the brackets, so there's two possibilities for a position in a formula to be the start of an address:

1. Next two characters are "R["
2. Next three characters are "RC["
   (Self referencing is not allowed, so we can exclude "RC".)

When we introduce absolute addresses, the brackets disappear and the general address format becomes R*rN*C*cN*. Now it gets more complicated to recognize an address and I'd prefer to stick to the two simple rules R[ and RC[. If I could convert absolute cell references to relative and return them in the R1C1 format, I could leave the current implementation unchanged.

I need to get a cell's formula in the R1C1 format, with all absolute cell references replaced by relative ones. It's theoretically very simple to remove absolute references from an address in the A1 format (Range.Formula property) by just removing all "$" signs. Alas, I don't know how to convert the address back to R1C1 format after doing that. Below is a naive implementation which fails on the penultimate row, but captures the idea I think. I have no clue on how to proceed or if it's even possible to do this as simply as I imagine.

```
Function returnRelativeFormulaR1C1(refCell As Range) As String
Dim refAddress As String, addressLength As Integer, posRow As Integer, posCol As Integer, iColNr As Integer
refAddress = refCell.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
addressLength = Len(refAddress)
iColNr = InStr(2, refAddress, "C")
posRow = Val(Mid(refAddress, 2, iColNr - 1)) ' Begin at 2, because there's always "R" at the beginning
posCol = Val(Mid(refAddress, iColNr + 1, addressLength - iColNr))

Dim formulaText As String
formulaText = Cells(posRow, posCol).Formula ' Get formula in A1 format

Dim formulaTextRelative As String
formulaTextRelative = Replace(formulaText, "$", "") ' Remove "$" signs, i.e. convert absolute references to relative

Dim convRange As Range
Set convRange = refCell
convRange.Cells(1, 1).Formula = formulaTextRelative ' Assign the converted formula to a virtual cell? The code fails here.

returnRelativeFormulaR1C1 = convRange.Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 ' If the previous row worked, this should then take care of the conversion back to R1C1 format.

End Function
```

Comment: Have a look at [precedents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.precedents)

Comment: Or, if you really want to stick with your current approach  look at [ConvertFormula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.convertformula)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to chris neilsen, ConvertFormula was just what I needed.

Corrected implementation of the conversion:

```
Function returnRelativeFormulaR1C1(refCell As Range) As String
Dim refAddress As String, addressLength As Integer, posRow As Integer, posCol As Integer, iColNr As Integer
refAddress = refCell.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
addressLength = Len(refAddress)
iColNr = InStr(2, refAddress, "C")
posRow = Val(Mid(refAddress, 2, iColNr - 1)) ' Begin at 2, because there's always "R" at the beginning
posCol = Val(Mid(refAddress, iColNr + 1, addressLength - iColNr))

Dim formulaTextA1 As String
formulaTextA1 = Cells(posRow, posCol).Formula ' Get formula in A1 format

Dim formulaTextA1Relative As String
formulaTextA1Relative = Replace(formulaTextA1, "$", "") ' Remove "$" signs, i.e. convert absolute references to relative
returnRelativeFormulaR1C1 = Application.ConvertFormula(Formula:=formulaTextA1Relative, fromReferenceStyle:=xlA1, toReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, RelativeTo:=refCell) ' Convert back to R1C1

End Function
```